# How to query objects of the same model in a model property

Tags: javascript, node.js, psql, objection.js

I am using objection.js, and I have this model, and would like to get other object instances that share the same property value as the current instance, e.g.

```
Example of model structure:

SomeModel {
  property1: 'string',
}


Objection.js: 

class SomeModel extends Model{
   static get tableName() {
       return 'some_model'
   }
}
```

and I would like to create a custom property that filters the model for others that share the same value so that I can get modelInstance.customProperty and it returns a list of filtered objects. Whats the best way to do it? I have tried using a virtualAttribute to no avail since queries should be in an async function, and virtual attribute doesnt support that

```
class SomeModel extends Model{
   static get tableName() {
       return 'some_model'
   }

   static get virtualAttributes() {
       return ['customProperty'];
   }

   async customProperty() {
      return SomeModel.query().where('property1', this.property1)
   }
}
```

I know that this approach is wrong but I hope you get an idea of what I am looking for

Edit:
So I tried using this approach instead, but Im not sure if its the best way to do it

```
class SomeModelHelper extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'some_model';
    }
}

class SomeModel extends Model{
   static get tableName() {
       return 'some_model';
   }

   static get virtualAttributes() {
       return ['customProperty'];
   }

   async $afterFind(args) {
       await SomeModelHelper.query()
       .where('property1', this.property1)
       .then(results => this.customProperty = results);
   }
}
```

Thanks to @rashomon's comment, I managed to solve it with

```
class SomeModel extends Model{
   static get tableName() {
       return 'some_model';
   }

   $afterFind(args) {
       SomeModel.query()
       .where('property1', this.property1)
       .then(results => this.customProperty = results);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `afterFind` hook:

```js
class SomeModel extends Model {
   static get tableName() {
       return 'some_model'
   }
   async $afterFind(args) {
       this.customProperty = await this.query()
         .where('property1', this.property1)
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, customProperty is undefined, do I need to define it in a virtualAttribute? and I tried creating a helper model like SomeModelHelper which is the same as SomeModel and use that instead in the query which works, but is it the best way to do it? And I noticed using async $afterFind instead of static async $afterFind works, combined with the helper model I mentioned

Comment: `$afterFind` makes sense. But creating a helper model should be not necessary. It doesnt work refering to `SomeModel`? (updated the response). Also then/catch syntax should not be mixed with async/await.

Comment: Nope, I assume it just enters an infinite loop, so it just fails

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, managed to make it work by just using SomeModel.query().then() without async/await, funnily enough your answer enters an infinite loop

Comment: You wellcome :) If you still want to give it a try without using a helper, I think you can use `this.query().where('property1', this.property1)` (or `this.$query().where('property1', this.property1)`, I am not familiar with v2 new methods)

Comment: Ah im sorry, I edited my answer wrongly, but yes i managed to do it without a helper thanks to your answer